# How to sort NSMutableArray which contains NSIndexPath integer array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I have a `NSMutableArray`.

It contains `NSIndexPaths` which itself a NSUInteger array.

Array looks like this

[

```
 (NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [1, 0, 0],   
 (NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [2, 1, 1],  
 (NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [1, 1, 0],  
 (NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [1, 0, 1],
```

.
.

]

Now i want to sort the `NSMutableArray` based on `NSIndexPath` integer array values. And the result should be following like this.

[

```
(NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [1, 0, 0],  
(NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [1, 0, 1],   
(NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [1, 1, 0],   
(NSIndexPath xxxxxxx) 3 indexes [2, 1, 1],
```

..

]

How to do it?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your `NSMutableArray` is called `indexPaths`, you could do:

```
[indexPaths sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than Maddy's suggestion, you might try using a custom NSSortDescriptor that applies the specific sorting rules you want.